# Python Dataframes: Describing a single column

Tags: python, dataframe, describe

Is there a way I can apply df.describe() to just an isolated column in a DataFrame.

For example if I have several columns and I use df.describe() - it returns and describes all the columns. From research, I understand I can add the following:

"A list-like of dtypes : Limits the results to the provided data types. To limit the result to numeric types submit numpy.number. To limit it instead to object columns submit the numpy.object data type. **Strings can also be used in the style of select_dtypes (e.g. df.describe(include=['O'])). To select pandas categorical columns, use 'category'"**

However I don't quite know how to write this out in python code. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df["your_column_name"].describe()` ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just add column name in square braquets:

```
df['column_name'].describe()
```

**Example:**

[image]

To get a **single column**:

```
df['1']
```

To get **several columns**:

```
df[['1','2']]
```

To get a **single row** by name:

```
df.loc['B']
```

or by index:

```
df.iloc[o]
```

To get a **specific field**:

```
df['1']['C']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].describe()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("ad.data", header=None)
data[111].describe()
```

or for example

```
lastindice = data[data .columns[-1]]
lastindice.describe()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pyspark DataFrame you can describe for only one column like this:

```
df.describe("col1").toPandas()
```

or several columns like this:

```
df.describe(["col1", "col2"]).toPandas()
```

Answer (score 0):

to describe it as table

```
df[['column_name']].describe()
```

to describe it as data

```
df['column_name'].describe()
```