# how to set the index as character for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a pandas df like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50274029/11074017).

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3) , columns=list('123'))
df
```

this piece of code gives

[image]

`describe()` gives

[image]

is there is way to set the name of each row (i.e. the index) in `df` as 'A', 'B', 'C' instead of '0', '1', '2' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.index`:

```
df.index=['A', 'B', 'C']

print(df)
   1  2  3
A  0  1  2
B  3  4  5
C  6  7  8
```

A more scalable and general solution would be using list-comprehension

```
df.index = [chr(ord('a') + x).upper() for x in df.index]

print(df)
   1  2  3
A  0  1  2
B  3  4  5
C  6  7  8
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `index` parameter in `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3) , 
                  index=list('ABC'),
                  columns=list('123'))
print (df)
   1  2  3
A  0  1  2
B  3  4  5
C  6  7  8
```